# change tr background color and hover link together with css

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table with a link on each row that should highlight on hover (both tr bgcolor and link). I can do this with javascript with the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 a:link, .style2 a:visited {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}
-->
</style>

<table class="style1" width=50%>
<tr     onMouseOver="document.getElementById('test').style.color='white'; this.style.backgroundColor='blue';"
    onMouseOut="document.getElementById('test').style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';"
    onClick="location.href='foo.html'">
            <td><a href="foo.html"><span id="test">link lala</span></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but I would like to do it with css.

I have tried the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style2 tr:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
.style2 {
    color: black;
}
.style2 a:link, .style2 a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.style2 a:hover {
    color: white;
}
-->
</style>

<table class="style2" width=50%>
   <tr>
      <td><a href="foo.html">link lala</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

but the link hover works only when the mouse goes on top of the link (not on top of the whole tr). There is also a problem with link that works only by clicking on the actual link (and not on the whole tr row).

I'm sure this can be done by using only css (at least the simultaneous hover).
Could you help me a bit?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a {
   display:block
}
```

This will make your `<a>` to take the full `<td>` and then not just the color will change when you hover the `<td>`, but also when you click on the whole `<td>` it will be an anchor (like button).

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood correctly this will solve your problem:

```
.style2 tr:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
.style2 tr:hover a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/56M4U/1/

Comment: What about the link though (in order to be clickable throughout the whole tr row? Is there any way to make it work without javascript?

Comment: You need `display: block;` - `<a style="display: block;" href="foo.html">link lala</a>`

Answer (score 1):

The `a` element is an inline element.  This means it will only take up enough space to fit it's contents.  As such the hover will only trigger when your mouse goes over this.

You can change this behaviour so that the `a` tag takes all available space in the `td` by changing it to a block level element by adding the following css.

```
.style2 a{ 
   display:block;
}
```

This will provide the results you need with the minimum fuss.

Note: This will only cause the `a` to take all space in the `td` element.  If the `td` column is the only one in the row, then this will work as expected, but if you add more columns; then only this particular column will trigger the link.

Comment: perfect, this solves the link problem as well (i added it in the .style2 a:link definition)

Comment: That will work, but bear in mind that `a:link` refers to an unvisited link. If you visit this link and comeback to the page, the above code will may not apply.  I add this in the `a` tag as it will apply to it regardless of whether it has been visited or not. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp for more info on the pseudo classes.

Comment: hmm, if I add cellpadding to the table then it doesn't work for this extra padding :/

Comment: As I explained in the note.  What the above code does is expand the `a` element to take up all the space of the `td`, which emulates the contents in your example.  But if you add other `td` columns/padding this effect will be lost, and you will have to revert back to using the javascript approach.

Comment: Ok, but isn't this a little bit strange? I mean it would be logical to expect that it would apply it to whatever the td would be. Btw, same thing happens if I add height to the td/tr (instead of padding). Perhaps there is another option that does the trick...

Comment: Think of the tags as boxes.  You have set the `a` box to take up all the space of the `td` box.  But if make the `td` box's walls thicker, would you expect the `a` box's walls to become thicker also? By adding padding margin etc to `tr`/`td` you are expecting to `a` element to change.  Perhaps `javascript` is the best approach for what you are trying to achieve. But bear in mind, you will need to add some click handling code to activate the anchor.

Comment: Have you tried `tr:hover`. Older browsers do not support this, but it might be what you need.

Comment: If you look at my original posted code, you'll see that I've already done the click handling with js, so that's not a problem:) I'd also tried tr:hover, but this highlights only the tr, not the link...

Comment: You will need a combination of both to provide the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that but you have to give a class to `<a>` tag.

and after that you can write css :

```
.style2 tr:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
.style2 tr:hover a.a_link {
    color: white;
}
```

and then

```
<table class="style2" width=50%>
   <tr>
      <td><a class="a_link" href="foo.html">link lala</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```